# Best approach to custom reporting system for Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, reporting, myisam

I have database of about 5 tables. I am going to need to get reports from the data in these tables with multiple join's etc. quite often. I was going to build a reporting feature in PHP but was wondering the best approach. I only have a MyISAM engine and it cannot be changed.
The best way I can think of is to create 2 of each table and use a trigger to write the same row to both tables, and grabbing reports from one set only.
If you think there is a better way than this I would love to try it!

Comment: Man, so Ipower.com does not allow for InnoDb so no transactions and it does not support triggers. Hmmmm... As per my comment below, I don't have access to the the .cnf files. Any other suggestions. Maybe a cron job to just drop and replicate the table each night?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just set up [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) and run all my reports on the slave.  I do this for a couple of systems I run.  Usually a separate VPS so that reporting load doesn't affect anything in production.

Comment: This seems like the way to go but I'm hosting on Ipower and I'm pretty sure I don't have access to the my.cnf. If I can get around this, I like the approach. Thanks!